# Mysql Connecting remotely

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I'm having a problem running a MySQL server that is hosted on another server that isn't the web hosting server. Currently my web server is running on godaddy's free linux hosting. They do offer a MySQL database free, but you can't connect remotely (Sequel Pro OSX program) without paying for an upgraded hosting plan. So temporally, I'm going to host the database on my server at home (XAMPP). Well, whenever I try to connect to the database using the PHP command mysql_connect() I'm getting an error:

```
"Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110"
```

before it was saying 113 (I believe).

Any-who, I tied to use the 'Bind-address' and changed it from 12.0.0.1 to my LAN IP. it didn't work or I didn't do it right. So, any help I can get on this would be awesome.

FYI, I can connect to the database remotely from inside my network using Sequel Pro. But the godaddy server can't connect. Port is open also, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Sounds like permissions problem to me. Have you granted all permissions to the go daddy site to access your local DB? Also, as a little tip- making the bind-address '0.0.0.0' will make mysql listen on all interfaces.

Comment: I tried the bind-address="0.0.0.0", nothing. didn't work. but thanks for the time. when I first intall XAMPP I had the change the permissions to allow remote connecting inside my network using PHPMyAdmin and it work. Not sure why it's not working outside my network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the mouth of a godaddy support guy, "Our shared hosting plans do not give you the ability to connect to an external database. If you wish to have this ability, you would need to look into one of our server hosting options."

So, my configuration is correct, it's just godaddy has it blocked. Lame! Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: That is correct.  Go Daddy hosting does not allow for you to connect to a third party database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hosting your database to a home local machine, you should also redirect router "***xxx***" TCP port to 3306 TCP port of hosting pc.
Remember you must connect to WAN ip on port "***xxx***".

1. You can use free dns services like dyndns to map your internet connection to a name (example yourname.dyndns.org)
2. Redirect a port (default 3306) of your router to 3306 TC port of your hosting pc (internal)
3. From remote pc connect to yourname.dydns.org:3306 or to port you redirected on router

Comment: And connect to the WAN (public) IP, not the internal LAN IP, in case that's what's going on.

Comment: But isn't MySQL hosted on port 3306? (ah, I see you changed the port, never mind about my question)

Comment: I think "redirect router" means "port forwarding". You may need to configure firewall on host PC also.

Comment: @Throdne: yes, just a typo :)

Comment: hmmm, Something new information. I can remotely connect to my database using an iphone app (MySQL Mobile Database Client) (wi-fi off, only using cellular signal) and it connects just fine.

Comment: well this is how I have it set up. godaddy web server at ADomain.net then I have a A (host) at server.ADomain.net that is pointing to my home server. (it works because when I go to that url it correctly shows my XAMPP main page.) so there is no need for dyndns.org